# Ошибка при открытии activity

Tags: java, android

Помогите, пожалуйста, делаю вкладки в стиле Material Design с сайта [этого](http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-vkladki-tablayout-v-stile-material-design/).
Пытаюсь добавить их в своё приложение, но вылетает ошибка при открытии той активити, где они как бы сделаны. Что я делаю не так?

**Ошибка:**

```
  05-05 10:40:26.410 3646-3646/com.example.admin.orshagoes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.orshagoes/com.example.admin.orshagoes.number_1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:207)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:130)
    at com.example.admin.orshagoes.number_1.onCreate(number_1.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5236)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)  
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Код активити:**

```
package com.example.admin.orshagoes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.example.admin.orshagoes.Time.Stop1;



public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] arr; //={"Вокзал", "Школа №12"};
    ListView listView1;
    String[] arro;
    //List<String> adapterList;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //arro = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1ob);
        //arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //adapterList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

       // listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
      //  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
      //  listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        startActivity(new Intent(number_1.this, Stop1.class));
                        break;

                }

            }
        });
    }

        // setMyAdapter(adapter);
        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "People");
            adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Group");
            adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "Calls");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Файл styles.xml обновленный:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Androidmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.orshagoes">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".number_1"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_1b"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_2"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_3"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_3a"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_5"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_5a"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_6"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_7"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".number_8"
            android:label="Остановки" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Time.Stop1"
            android:label="Расписание" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity number 1.xml
Может, тут что-то?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Проблема в стилях. Покажите их. Вам нужен стиль с родителем, cодержащим `NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Согласно ошибке вам вы пытаетесь назначить `ActionBar` в активити, которая уже имеет оный.

Чтобы использовать свой `toolbar` как `actionBar` вам надо в стилях указать, что у актиивити нет `ActionBar` - т.е. объявление стиля должно быть таким:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

И этот стиль должен быть назначен каждой актиивти/сразу всему приложению.

Comment: Когда добавляю эту строчку, тема вообще исчезает и все ровно при нажатии приложение остановилось

Comment: Покажите в вопросе обновленные стили и манифест

Comment: Не пойму что с этими стилями не так...

Comment: @Milevoje, у меня одна идея осталась - удалить всё кроме первого стиля.